# show different phone number based on the country in angular 8

Tags: angular, localization, geolocation, internationalization

I am working on an angular app where on a page, I need to show different cust care number for different country,

> For Example,

1. If user is logged-in from UK i will show  1-800-456-7891
2. If user is logged-in from USA i will show  1-800-555-4444
3. If user is logged-in from  Japan, I will show  1-800-666-7474.

I am not positive on using i18n module, of angular, as website is in english only.

I thought of using HTML5 GeoLocation api to get the logged-in user country but than if depends on user to share the location info OR not.

can someone suggest me the best way of achieving this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use one of the free services like : [**GEOJS**](https://www.geojs.io/) or **[IPSTACK](https://ipstack.com/)**

Example :

**HTTP GET** : `https://get.geojs.io/v1/ip/country/41.249.34.194.json`

**return** : `{"name":"Morocco","country":"MA","ip":"41.249.34.194","country_3":"MAR"}`

NOTICE: *IPSTACK have a limited quota 10000 request*

Comment: is it safe to use these sites in production?? does angular has something in-built for this situation?

Comment: With angular, you can use the HTML5 GeoLocation API.

Comment: As I mentioned in my question, GEO location API has an drawback where user need to allow to show the location what if user deny than I Will not get the user location.

Comment: if user doesn't allow to show the location then use his address ip